# Add new column to a matrix in scheme

Tags: scheme

The matrix that i have is this:
    
    `(define matr '('("Шаран" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да")
                   '("Гълъб" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Да")
                   '("Котка" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не")
                   '("Куче" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не")))`

I Want to add one more column at the end of the matrix.

My current code is this:
    `(define (matrix-add-column matr new-row new-matr)
      (cond
        [(null? matr) new-matr]
          [(matrix-add-column (cdr matr) (cdr new-row) (cons new-matr (append (cadar matr) (car new-row))))]))`

The output of this command `(matrix-add-column matr '("Не" "Не" "Не" "Да") '())` is:

```
'((((() "Шаран" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" . "Не") "Гълъб" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Да" . "Не") "Котка" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" . "Не")
  "Куче"
  "Да"
  "Да"
  "Да"
  "Не"
  "Не"
  "Не"
  "Не"
  "Да"
  "Не"
  .
  "Да")
```

I don't like it. My new matrix should look like the original but with one more column. It would be even better if the column goes on the original matrix not a copy.

If you ask why in one point I use (cadar matr) it is because

```
(car matr)
''("Шаран" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да")
(cadar matr)
'("Шаран" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't really want your matrix to a be list of *quoted* lists, something like this, perhaps?

```
(define (matrix-add-column matrix column)
  (map append matrix (map list column)))
```

Example:

```
> (define matr '(("Шаран" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да")
                 ("Гълъб" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Да")
                 ("Котка" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не")
                 ("Куче" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не")))
> (matrix-add-column matr '("Не" "Не" "Не" "Да"))
'(("Шаран" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не")
  ("Гълъб" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да" "Да" "Не")
  ("Котка" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Не")
  ("Куче" "Да" "Да" "Да" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Не" "Да" "Не" "Да"))
```